# URL in JOptionPane

Tags: java

How can I add a clickable URL into a JOptionPane (in the middle of a text) ?

Comment: This other answer has a pretty nice solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any component to a JOPtionPane. So you can add a JEditorPane containing HTML with your clickable URL. That is the "message" Object which is passed as a parameter to the showXXX methods can be a Swing component.