# How to open a link from JDialog's text?

Tags: java, html, hyperlink, jdialog

I have this code:

```
String message = <html><a href="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/">http://www.videolan.org/vlc/</a></html>

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        message, 
        "Error", 
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, 
        new ImageIcon(LeCTo.class.getResource("/images/logo.png")));
```

And I want when user clicks on the link that an internet browser opens but that is not happening.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane/8348281#comment10297245_8348281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this question answered, solution is in camickr's comment:

[stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane/8348281#comment10297245_8348281).