# JOptionPane with clickable link

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to have a clickable link with my JoptionPane message box. I got started with this link: [clickable links in JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane) but it does not seem to work and the link is not clickable. How could I do this?

Comment: Make a JLabel, configure as you like, add a MouseListener to it. Use this JLabel as the "message" parameter to the JOptionPane, when mouseClicked is called, use Desktop to "browse" to the link location

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by @camickr in the link that you have shared works... with a little more digging

Here is what I did

I had to set the EditorKit of the JEditorPane to be able to process "text/html" and then I made the JEditorPane non editable, then I had to handle the Hyperlink by implementing a HyperlinkListener and it worked!

Here is my code:

```
public class HtmlInSwing {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JOptionPane optionPane;
    private static JEditorPane editorPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Demo frame...");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        optionPane = new JOptionPane();
        optionPane.setSize(400, 300);
        editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        panel.add(optionPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        optionPane.add(editorPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editorPane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
        editorPane.setEditable(false);

        HyperlinkListener hyperlinkListener = new     ActivatedHyperlinkListener(frame, editorPane);
        editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(hyperlinkListener);

        editorPane.setText("<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>Go to the     stack</a>");

        editorPane.setToolTipText("if you click on <b>that link you go to     the stack");

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

And here is an illustrative image:

[image: jeditorpane with html inside]

Now here is the HyperlinkListener's implementation.

```
class ActivatedHyperlinkListener implements HyperlinkListener {

    Frame frame;

    JEditorPane editorPane;

    public ActivatedHyperlinkListener(Frame frame, JEditorPane editorPane) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.editorPane = editorPane;
    }

    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent hyperlinkEvent) {
        HyperlinkEvent.EventType type = hyperlinkEvent.getEventType();
        final URL url = hyperlinkEvent.getURL();
        if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        } else if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            System.out.println("Activated");
            Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            Document doc = editorPane.getDocument();
            try {
                editorPane.setPage(url);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "Error following link", "Invalid link",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                editorPane.setDocument(doc);
            }
        }
      };
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runner);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the result (I will leave the cosmetic details to be fixed by you, as I am simply illustrating that it works!)

[image]