# Clickable links from ArrayList in JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm trying to implement a history-button in my `Browser class` (created in eclipse), and I want the links in the button to be clickable. Here is my code that gets initiated when the user presses the button `History`:

```
private void showMessage() {
    try {
        String message = new String();
        message = history.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Something is wrong with your historylist!");
    }
}
```

In the code above, `history` is a list with all the webpages that has been previously visited.

I have tried using the method presented here:
[clickable links in JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane), and I got it to work. The problem is, this solution only lets me predefine URL:s, but I want my list `history` to be displayed, and the URLs in it to be clickable.

For example, if I have visited https://www.google.com and https://www.engadget.com, the list will look like this: `history = [www.google.com, www.engadget.com]`, and both links should be separately clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function that should be called when someone presses the `history`-button. It uses a `JEditorPane` with a `HyperlinkListener`. The string `html` in the code below adds the needed html-coding so that the `HyperlinkListener` can read and visit the webpages.

```
public void historyAction() {
    String html = new String();
    for (String link : history) {
        html = html + "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link + "</a>\n";
    }
    html = "<html><body" + html + "</body></html>";
    JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
    ep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)) {
                loadURL(e.getURL().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    ep.setEditable(false);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ep);
}
```