# How can I get the version of the currently executing launcher?

Tags: java, install4j

My current attempt is:

```
File executionDir = new File("").getCanonicalFile();
ApplicationInfo info = ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(executionDir);
return info.getVersion();
```

It works, but I wonder if there is a way to get at the information without making any assumptions about the current working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `sys.version` compiler variable:

```
import com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables;

try {
    String version = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.version");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO not running in installation
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but the import has extra Variables at end. It should be `import com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables;`

Comment: I verified this works great with install4j 10.

Answer (score 0):

As a more complete working code sample, here is the update check from https://jaerproject.org :

```
    public static String INSTALL4J_UPDATES_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SensorsINI/jaer/master/updates.xml";

   public static void checkForInstall4jReleaseUpdate(Component parent) {
        // check if rujning from installed version of jaer (fails if running from git compiled jaer)
        String currentVersion="unknown";
        try {
            currentVersion = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.version");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO not running in installation
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html> Could not determine current version. <p>To check for udpates, you need to install jAER with an install4j installer. <p>(Probably are you running from git compiled development environment): <p>" + e.toString(), "Version check error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        String updateUrl = INSTALL4J_UPDATES_URL;
        try {
            UpdateDescriptor updateDescriptor = UpdateChecker.getUpdateDescriptor(updateUrl, ApplicationDisplayMode.GUI);
            if (updateDescriptor.getPossibleUpdateEntry() != null) {
                // TODO an update is available, execute update downloader
                UpdateDescriptorEntry updateDescriptorEntry = updateDescriptor.getEntryForCurrentMediaFileId();
                String updateVersion = updateDescriptorEntry.getNewVersion();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, 
                        new MessageWithLink("<html>Current version: "+currentVersion+"<p> Update " + updateVersion + 
                                " is available; see <a href=\"https://github.com/SensorsINI/jaer/releases\">jAER releases</a>"), 
                                "Update available", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
//                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html>Update " + updateVersion + " is available; see <a href=\"https://github.com/SensorsINI/jaer/releases\">jAER releases</a>", "Releases update check", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, new MessageWithLink("<html>No update available;<br> you are running current release " + currentVersion+"<p>See <a href=\"https://github.com/SensorsINI/jaer/releases\">jAER releases</a>"), "No update available", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (IOException | UserCanceledException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "Could not check for release update: " + e.toString(), "Update check error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

It uses the handy `MessageWithLink` class from [clickable links in JOptionPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348063/clickable-links-in-joptionpane) to show a clickable link to the project releases page in the JOptionPane.

```
/**
 *
 * Usage: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new MessageWithLink("Here is a
 * link on <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>"));
 *
 */
public class MessageWithLink extends JEditorPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MessageWithLink(String htmlBody) {
        super("text/html", "<html><body style=\"" + getStyle() + "\">" + htmlBody + "</body></html>");
        addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)) {
                    // Process the click event on the link (for example with java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse())
//                    System.out.println(e.getURL() + " was clicked");
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                        } catch (IOException|URISyntaxException ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        setEditable(false);
        setBorder(null);
    }

    static StringBuffer getStyle() {
        // for copying style
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        Font font = label.getFont();
        Color color = label.getBackground();

        // create some css from the label's font
        StringBuffer style = new StringBuffer("font-family:" + font.getFamily() + ";");
        style.append("font-weight:" + (font.isBold() ? "bold" : "normal") + ";");
        style.append("font-size:" + font.getSize() + "pt;");
        style.append("background-color: rgb(" + color.getRed() + "," + color.getGreen() + "," + color.getBlue() + ");");
        return style;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new MessageWithLink("Here is a link on <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>"));

    }
}
```

This is a very simple example of that can be done with install4j updaters but enough for our project.