# install4j: How can I get the compile date / timestamp of the currently executing launcher at runtime?

Tags: java, install4j

Similar question to [how to get the Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69244137/install4j-how-can-i-get-the-version-of-the-currently-executing-launcher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the `sys.timestamp` compiler variable:

```
import com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.Variables;

try {
    String version = Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.timestamp");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO not running in installation
}
```